# JavaScript: отличие Firebug от Google Chrome консоли

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, отладка, firebug

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-нибудь принципиальные отличия между плагином Firebug и инструментом разработчика Google Chrome?

И то, и другое, предназначено для отладки, но в чем разница?

У какого приложения больше преимуществ или здесь действует принцип кому что нравится?

Спасибо!

Comment: разница в том, для какого браузера они применяются

Comment: @Grundy, т.е. разница только в браузерах, а функционал тот же?

Comment: Первый - плагин, второй же - часть браузера, т. е. больше свободы. Что до функциональности - примерна одна и та же, сейчас все инструменты разработчика как клоны, наверное просто больше ничего не нужно.

Comment: Постоянных принципиальных отличий нет. Это два продукта занимающие одну и ту же нишу: когда что-то появляется в одном, это тут же стараются сделать в другом. Лично я когда-то пользовался фаербагом, потому что мне больше нравился его интерфейс, но однажды у меня стало ощутимо тормозить одно сложное spa при включенном фаербаге (какие-то утечки памяти в нем), я перешел на chrome dev tools и привык.